# Params not updating on state change ,react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have a react native app with 2 screens ,the first one is supposed to receive updates from a server and updates its state , upon clicking a submit button the app navigates to another screen that is dependent on the state of the first , i have managed to pass the values via the params and retrieve them in the second screen however i can not seem to get the updated values from the first screen as they are being replaced periodically ,how can i go about it, should i pass a reference of the object to the second screen and if so how would i go about it ..

The first screen , note the state in this screen is updating well and fine i console logged it after each setState , its the second screen that's not receiving the updates

```js
 handleSubmit = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Tracking Bus", this.state.bus);
    };


  render() {   
    
    return (
      
          <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this.handleSubmit}>
            <View
              style={{
                width: 330,
                height: 40,
                backgroundColor: "#6FCF97",
                alignSelf: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center", fontSize: 20 }}>Submit</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableNativeFeedback>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

The Second Screen , render function i.e

```js
 render() {
    

    return (
      
 setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.props.route.params.bus.location[1]);
    }, 2000);
  })
```

am expecting to get updated values but i i just get the initial values

Comment: Don't think you can reference an instance from a previous screen like this. How about updating the second screen to consume this.props.route.params.bus. Then, second screen can run setInterval() logic to update bus.location (whatever logic is in the first screen)

Comment: Do you want the data to be updated dinamically from one screen to another ? Or does the update require an action from you ? If it's the first case then you will need a context/state management (Or a parent component) for this

Comment: @alex the set interval is in the second screen an it is consuming the value from the firstif thats what you mean

Comment: @QuentinGrisel yes i want it updated dynamically , thanks will look into that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work :

```
 handleSubmit = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Tracking Bus", {bus:this.state.bus});
    };
```

and in your second screen:

```
 render() {
    

    return (
      
 setInterval(() => {
      const bus= this.props.navigation.getParam('bus');
      console.log(bus);
    }, 2000);
  })
```

Comment: if this helped you it will helpful if you upvote my answer :)

Comment: sure no prob ;)

Answer (score -1):

You are passing the params incorrectly from first screen. You can try this and your fetching logic seems fine as `this.props.route.params.bus`

```
 handleSubmit = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Tracking Bus", {  params: {bus : this.state.bus} });
    };
```

Comment: Could you please upvote and accept the answer if it helped. Thanks :)